# Java 2D object repeatition

Tags: java, 2d

I built a Java 2d circle using the Java `g.drawstring()` methods and using the Breseham's Circle algorithm and I used it to draw a  smiley but when I move the smiley it repeats all over the screen I know for sure that the `PaintComponent(Graphics g)`  Method keeps re-drawing the simley at different location specified but how to correct this logic error is my problem. Here are the codes i wrote.

```
public class Midsemester extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
// objects class
static Movement move = new Movement();
public int x = 0, y = 0, x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, x3 = 0, y3 = 0, x4 = 0, y4 = 0;
private int inix = 0, iniy = 0;
static String[] st = {"xy","x1y1","x2y2","x3y3","x4y4"};
static shapes shaper = new shapes();//object class contain the algorithms used to draw the circles using the Breseham's Circle algorithm  


public Midsemester()
{

}
/****/


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   super.paintComponents(g);

   x = (int)move.x;
   y = (int)move.y;
   x1 = (int)move.x1;
   y1 = (int)move.y1;
   x2 = (int)move.x2;
   y2 = (int)move.y2;
   x3 = (int)move.x3;
   y3 = (int)move.y3;
   x4 = (int)move.x4;
   y4 = (int)move.y4;

   shaper.draw_floor(100, 350, 1350, g);
   shaper.draw_wall(100, 0, 350, g);
   shaper.create(x,y,50,g, Color.yellow);//creates the smileys in there different colors
   shaper.create(x1,y1,50,g, Color.BLUE);
   shaper.create(x2,y2,50,g, Color.pink);
   shaper.create(x3,y3,50,g, Color.magenta);
   shaper.create(x4,y4,50,g, Color.orange);

   repaint();

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    float[] values = move.firstscenemovement(500,200,st[0]);
    repaint();
    System.out.println("x:"+values[0] + "\ny:" + values[1]);
}
}
```

The image repeats or trails as it moves would have posted an image but i need a 10 reputation to do.

How can I correct this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think The `repaint()` in your `paintComponent()` code causes an endless recursion.

repaint --> paintComponent --> repaint -->...

This is messing up the Graphics object.

**edit:**

There is another error in your code, your calling super.paintComponent **s** (g) instead of `super.paintComponent(g)`. Try to use the method without the **s**.

Here is a simple example of a class that moves the string according to the position of the last click:

---

```java
public class Test extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private int x = 100;
    private int y = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        Test test = new Test();
        jFrame.add(test);
        jFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.addMouseListener(test);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("blub", x, y);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.x = e.getX();
        this.y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Even after removing the repaint() method at the paintcomponent(Graphics g) it still does not slove the problem but at the actionlistener code section it does not move the object

Answer (score 0):

You are the first questioner i have found who is calling `super.paintComponent(g)` in the overridden `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function in *their first posted question*. Well,

calling `repaint()` will actually submit a new paint request resulting another invocation of `paintComponenr(Graphics g)` function and putting `repaint()` inside the `paintComponent` function is going to create a cycle, calling painting functions one after another increasing the rendering stack. So remove the `repaint()` call from the `paintComponent` function.

Check out the tutorial: [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)